# item reader in spring batch is not able to read a oracle table

Tags: oracle11g, spring-batch

Item reader in spring batch is able to read other tables But it is not able to read a table. But I am able to read it in sql developer. I am getting exception like reader initialization failed.
Can Someone help me on this?

Comment: Show the code and configuration that is failing. And be specific in your question and statements: what exception (exactly) are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake i have done. The user which i am using in java to access db hasn't privilege for the table i am trying to access.. In SQL developer i am using the user which has privilege for all the tables. 
Thanks a lot for your response and time.